# beautifulsoup find unique div tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

Working with bs4. When trying to find html info inside `<div data-reactroot>` I am never able to locate it.

Inside `<div data-reactroot>` I am going to have to loop through each text entry and split it. I get how to find a normal tags but `data-reactroot` seems to be giving me a lot of trouble.

```
<div data-reactroot="">
   <div>
      <div class="_hgs47m">
         <div class="_1thk0tsb">
            <div style="margin-right:8px">
               <div class="_1ciyl4o"><span class="_8tbpu3" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="_n5lh69r">
            <div class="_1p3joamp">Entire guest suite</div>
            <div class="_36rlri">
               <div class="_36rlri" style="margin-right:24px">
                  <div class="_czm8crp">2 guests</div>
               </div>
               <div class="_36rlri" style="margin-right:24px">
                  <div class="_czm8crp">1 bedroom</div>
               </div>
               <div class="_36rlri" style="margin-right:24px">
                  <div class="_czm8crp">1 bed</div>
               </div>
               <div class="_36rlri" style="margin-right:0">
                  <div class="_czm8crp">1 bath</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:16px">
         <div class="_hgs47m">
            <div class="_1thk0tsb">
               <div style="margin-right:8px">
                  <div class="_1ciyl4o"><span class="_8tbpu3" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_n5lh69r">
               <div><span class="_1p3joamp">Self check-in</span></div>
               <div class="_czm8crp">Check yourself in with the keypad.</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:16px">
         <div class="_hgs47m">
            <div class="_1thk0tsb">
               <div style="margin-right:8px">
                  <div class="_1ciyl4o"><span class="_8tbpu3" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_n5lh69r">
               <div><span class="_1p3joamp">Sparkling clean</span></div>
               <div class="_czm8crp">9 recent guests said this place was sparkling clean.</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:16px">
         <div class="_hgs47m">
            <div class="_1thk0tsb">
               <div style="margin-right:8px">
                  <div class="_1ciyl4o"><span class="_8tbpu3" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="_n5lh69r">
               <div><span class="_1p3joamp">Michael &amp; Tammy is a Superhost</span></div>
               <div class="_czm8crp">Superhosts are experienced, highly rated hosts who are committed to providing great stays for guests.</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:24px;margin-bottom:24px">
         <div class="_7qp4lh"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
data_soup.find_all("div data-reactroot")
data_soup.get('data-reactroot')
```

Comment: is that a little better?

Comment: Seems like you might be after: `soup.find('div', attrs={'data-reactroot': True})` ?

Comment: yes just a little better ! A well explained question receives bunch of answers with different approaches  from them you can select better which suite you.... but for this some must things should be added to the question- like  what you tried in brief description then what code you have done, then error you got at you stuck on then what other options you tried then what other error you got, then what are the references you used, what is the expected output and what you getting then other dependent references and files code like html structure, web url, git link etc. NEVER add screenshot of code